# Não aplicar regra de CSS em apenas uma página

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma classe em CSS que eu gostaria que **não** fosse aplicada quando eu estiver em uma página: exemplo.com.br/teste

Tem como eu fazer isso com alguma regra do CSS?

Essa é a classe:

```
.section-name {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: infelizmente não, o correto seria criar uma classe com nome diferente e aplicar ou não quando necessario.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode botar uma classe exclusiva no `body`da sua página. Por exemplo, na página `exemplo.com.br/teste`, voce poderia colocar a classe: `exclusive` no `body`. Depois no seu CSS você coloca:

```
body:not(.exclusive) .section-name {
    display: none;
}
```

Nesse caso ele seria aplicado em todos os `.section-name`, a não ser que aquela classe esteja aplicada no `body`.

**EDIT - WORDPRESS**

Como você pediu por Wordpress, eu vou dar alguns conselhos. Porém tem um tempo que não trabalho com Wordpress. Enfim, você pode ainda usar a técnica que eu te mostrei acima, só que você vai precisar de uma maneira de adicionar o final da sua url como uma classe da `body` da página.
No Wordpress eles chamam isso de Page Slug, e você pode procurar por plugins que fazem isso automaticamente, como [esse](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-url-slugs-as-body-classes/).

Procurei saber também, mas não tenho como testar no momento, mas aparentemente, colocando esta função no *functions.php* do tema, terá o mesmo efeito:

```
//Page Slug Body Class
function add_slug_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    if ( isset( $post ) ) {
        $classes[] = $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name;
    }
    return $classes;
    }
    add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_slug_body_class' );
}
```

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar que é Wordpress. As páginas são criadas dinamicamente.

Comment: Mas você consegue [adicionar classes ao `body`](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-to-the-body-class-in-wordpress--cms-21077) com WordPress.

Comment: @FelipeStoker Dei uma atualizada.